# From Where & Who can manage the Users' information inside Delve

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile, exchange-server, delve

I am working on a sharepoint online tenant which is under "Office 365 Enterprise E3" plan. and when i click on a username inside a sharepoint site, i will be redirected to the user's delve page. which contain info such as :-

1. the user's direct manager.
2. the employee which have are under the user.
3. the user's email, phone number, job title.

so my question, is from where we can change these information? is it something managed/covered by sharepoint online or by online active directory ?

second question, in general who have the permission to modify the above users' information?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If using Azure AD Connect, this information is replicated from on-prem Active Directory to Azure AD and then to SharePoint Online.

If not using Azure AD Connect, then the info comes from Azure AD and is replicated to SharePoint Online.

The people who can modify that information will either be the user, or someone who was delegated access to those users in AD or Azure AD.

Comment: thanks for the valuable reply. Now in our case we are on an intermediate stage, so some of the users' information are still on on-prem AD while other are on Azure AD. But as a result, can I say that in all ways, managing users' info inside their Delve pages are managed inside Active Directory (either Azure AD or on-prem AD) and not inside sharepoint, is this correct? second question you mentioned the following `The people who can modify that information will either be the user,..` so are you saying that users can change their info such as their direct manager, job title by themselves?

Comment: can you advice on my above comment?

Comment: Some data is managed by the end user (skills, education, for example) while other data comes from Azure AD (mail, title, and so on). How that data gets into Azure AD (directly or via AAD Connect) is irrelevant to SharePoint Online.

Comment: but for the direct manager of the user and for the job title, these need to come from Azure and can not be managed and edited by end user? second question for the info that can be managed by end users such as skills, education, etc will they be updating them from sharepoint or from Azure AD or other sources??

Comment: For those profile properties that are end user managed, they will only be available in the user's SharePoint profile. There is no replication of data from SharePoint to any other directory system.

Comment: ok i got your point, actually our users have been modifying their "skills" & "about me" message from sharepoint, so i was not sure if those will actually be saved inside AD or inside SP.. but what about the organization block, are those managed inside sharepoint online, or inside Azure AD? i mean by Organization block, the block insdie the Delve page which shows the direct manager of the current user and the employees that works under him,, are the Organization chart managed inside sharepoint or inside Azure AD?